# On maximal ideals of $x\mathbb{Q}[[x]]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, power-series, ideals

> Let $\mathbb{Q}[[x]]-$  be a formal power series ring ([definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Ring_structure)). Let $ R=x\mathbb{Q}[[x]]$. Prove that $R$ doesn't contain any maximal ideal.

As I understood elements of $R$ are power series without constant term. I don't know where to start, any help is appreciated